# Irreducible isomorphic subgroups of $ SU(n) $ that are not conjugate

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

What is an example of two irreducible (closed) subgroups $ H_1,H_2 $ of $ SU(n) $ which are isomorphic but not conjugate?

For $ SU(2) $ there are no examples like this since isomorphic (closed) subgroups of $ SU(2) $ are always conjugate.

If we drop the assumption of irreducibility then $ diag(\zeta_3,\zeta_3,\zeta_3) $ and $ diag(1,\zeta_3,\zeta_3^2) $ both generate cyclic $ 3 $ subgroups of $ SU(3) $ which are isomorphic but not conjugate.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53955/which-compact-groups-have-nonisomorphic-irreducible-representations-of-the-same

Comment: @MoisheKohan Interesting link! Could you help me better understand the precise relationship between a compact group $ H $ having non-isomorphic irreps of the same dimension and the answer to my question? For example, the finite group $ H=SL(2,5) $ has two non-isomorphic irreps of dimension $ 2 $, but nonetheless it is the case that all subgroups of $ SU(2) $ isomorphic to $ SL(2,5) $ are conjugate.

Comment: Just think about it a bit more and keep in mind that simple compact connected Lie groups have only inner automorphisms.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I thought the simple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group simply connected compact connected Lie groups of types $ A_n, n \geq 2 $ and $ D_n, n \geq 4 $ and $ E_6 $ all had nontrivial outer automorphisms? But I see that the two $ C_n $ fundamental reps from your link should work as examples.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the automorphisms of the Dynkin diagram. But the link will give you examples not coming from diagram automorphisms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the two non conjugate $ Sp(3) $ subgroups of $ SU(6) $ are the minimal counterexample.

However I would be interested in isomorphic but non conjugate irreducible subgroups of $ SU(5) $ if such things exist. I feel mildly confident that no examples like this exist for $ SU(3) $ or $ SU(4) $.

$ Sp(n) $ and $ SO(2n+1) $ have the same dimension and often behave similarly in other ways (especially if you compare $ Sp(n) $ to $ Spin(2n+1) $ or $ PSp(n) $ to $ SO(2n+1) $).

$ SO(7) $ has two non conjugate irreps in $ SU(7) $. This is certainly not more minimal but it is interesting.